# Is local coop possible with 2 separate accounts in Victor Vran?

Tags: ps4, victor-vran

My brother and I both own a copy of Victor Vran for the PS4. Usually we play separately of each other, but every now and then we like to play together (on one screen). However, it seems that local coop characters are stored on the PSN account of player one (my PSN account), this means my brother doesn't have access to this character when he gets back home.

Is it possible to start a local coop game using a second PSN account for player 2?